# Erro ao usar pow(a,b)

Tags: c, matemática

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main() {

double pi = 3.14159;
double R, A;

scanf("%lf", &R);
A = (pi)* pow(double R, int 2);
printf("%lf\n", A);

return 0;
}
```

Esse codigo está retornando o erro: **Too few arguments to function 'pow'**
por que?

Comment: Já agora: math.h já define pi: `M_PI * pow(R,2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente chamar a função da seguinte forma:

```
A = pi * pow(R, 2);
```

e veja se o erro persiste.

O parenteses no **pi** não é necessário (mas também não causa erro), o erro era porque você estava invocando a função com os tipos de dados, o que não é preciso

Comment: Ou melhor, substitua `pow(R, 2)` por `R * R`.

Comment: Se a potência for fixa, e um valor baixo como é o caso, é melhor mais fácil fazer como @VictorStafusa mencionou, a menos é claro que seja um trabalho que obrigue a usar a função Pow ou a potência seja variável ou desconhecida...

Comment: Problema resolvido, valeu! eu queria usar a função pow pra fixar mesmo... às vezes eu esqueço que ela existe, sou iniciante.